# how to make BottomNavBar persisent while switching to nested screens in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

```dart
List navScreens = [
  const HomeScreen(),
  const FavoriteScreen(),
  const NotificationScreen(),
  const MyProfilesScreen(),
];

Scaffold(
  body: navScreens.elementAt(selectedIndex),
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    currentIndex: selectedIndex,
    iconSize: 34,
    selectedItemColor: ConstColors.green,
    unselectedItemColor: ConstColors.black2,
    elevation: 10,
    onTap: (value) {
      setState(() {
        selectedIndex = value;
      });
    },
    items: const [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.home_outlined), label: 'home'),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.bookmark_border_outlined), label: 'favorite'),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.notifications_none), label: 'notification'),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.person_outline), label: 'profile'),
    ],
  ),
);
```

When I switch screens from `BottomNavBar` (MainScreen) to inside (DetailScreen), then `BottomNavBar` disappears. If I directly navigate to bottombar screen back from nested screens. It also get disappear. `Persistent_bottom_bar` is another solution but I want to fix it with built in support. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

This [package](https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar) suits your need well.

Comment: thanks, i knew about this package, if there is any built in support with Flutter BottomNavBar Widget itself.